# Get values in list of a JSON key

Tags: python, json

I'm doing an exercise where I have to find if there some elements in a JSON file and then delete them. For now the problem I have is finding the keys and values.

I have the following JSON called `menupizzeria.json`:

```
{
  "tama\u00f1ospizza": ["Personal", "Mediana", "Grande", "Extragrande"],
  "borde": [{"Normal": [0, 1, 2, 3]}, {"Queso": [1, 2]}],
  "masa": ["delgada", "sazonada"], 
  "salsas": ["roja", "rosada"], 
  "Ingredientes": ["cebolla", "3", "f", "g", "h", "r", "s", "", "a", "a"]
}
```

I'm trying to define a function that searches for the key, for example the key `"masa"` and if it is in the JSON then I would like to search for one of the values available in the list, for example `"delgada"`, but I'm having a hard time trying to get to the values. This is the code I'm using but I always get the keys. Is there a way to achieve what I want?

```
def read_menu(path):
    with open(path, "r", encoding='utf-8') as file:
        menu = json.load(file)
    return menu

def get_fields(input_data):
    fields = list(input_data)
    search = input("Please enter a field to search: ")
    result = []
    found = fields.index(search)
    indice = fields[found]
    if indice in fields:
        values = input(f"please enter a value to search: ")
        for field in input_data:
            if input_data[field] == values:
                result.append(field)
        if len(result) <= 0:
            print("NO results where found")
        elif len(resultado) == 1:
            print(f"one result was found: {result[0]} ")
        else:
            print(f"found {len(result)} results: ")
    else:
        print(f"found {len(resultado)} results")
    

menupi = read_menu("menupizzeria.json")
print(type(menupi))
get_fields(menupi)
```

Comment: I think you should try replacing the if condition `if input_data[field] == values` with `if values in input_data[field]` in order to search if `values` is in `input_data[field]` list

Comment: @taxevader you are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because input_data[field] is a list, it will never be equal to a string entered by the user. To check if a string is IN a list you can use

```
if value in input_data[field]
```